# Azure DNS Root Domain Pointing to Azure CDN Endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-cdn, azure-dns

If I were to use `Azure DNS`, can I point my root domain to an `Azure CDN` endpoint?

It's kind of like creating an `A` record that points to an `Azure CDN` endpoint.

Is this possible with `Azure DNS`?

Just to paint the big picture here, I'm trying to host a static website on `Azure` through `Blob Storage` AND want to be able to use my `root domain` with `https`. I'm aware I can point to a `host` such as `www.mydomain.com` but I want to point to my `root domain`.

I'm also aware that there are tricks I can use such as set up a `CNAME`  that points my `root domain` to `www.mydomain.com`.

I really don't want to use any of these workarounds and point my `root domain` to my `Azure CDN` endpoint and I'm willing to switch to `Azure DNS` for that IF it allows me to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, It's possible with Azure DNS. You could use **alias records** to [point your DNS zone apex to Azure CDN endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-alias#point-zone-apex-to-azure-cdn-endpoints).

For more details about [Announcing Alias records for Azure DNS](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-alias-records-for-azure-dns/)

Comment: I've done this but when I browse to root address the browser stops the connection and shows the "unsecure connection warning" for SSL. I done't get this warning for www though as I've set it up in CDN endpoint. Do we need to do any other step?

Comment: @CageE you may need to configure HTTPS on an Azure CDN custom domain. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-custom-ssl?tabs=option-1-default-enable-https-with-a-cdn-managed-certificate#tlsssl-certificates

Comment: I see but custom domain does not support root. "Enabling Https with CDN Managed Certificate is not supported anymore for apex (root) domains". As you've mentioned docs say alias record is the way but it doesn't solve the unsecure connection!

Comment: You need to use your own SSL certificate for root domain. You can see option 2 in that document.

Comment: If you "bring your own certificate" then you have to manually update it every time it expires. This is a poor solution.